# How to get CN from a certificate in Golang

Tags: go, certificate, x509certificate, x509

Is there any way to extract CN from X509Certificate in Golang.

Previously we did something like this in Java.

```
private String getCNFromCertificate() throws InvalidNameException, CertificateException, IOException {
      X509Certificate certificate = getCert(DeploymentConfiguration.getPemCertPath().get());
      String commonName = new LdapName(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()).getRdns().stream()
              .filter(i -> i.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CN")).findFirst().get().getValue().toString();
        return commonName;
}
```

Are there any packages in Golang which can do similar task. Or what could be better alternative to extract CN from Certificate in Golang.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of how to load & parse a public cert:

```
bs, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/google.crt")  // handle error

block, _ := pem.Decode(bs)
if block == nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to parse PEM block containing the public key")
}

cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes) // handle error

log.Printf("Subject:   %q", cert.Subject)

// Subject:   "CN=*.google.com"
```

Warning: since `go 1.15` the use of [CN to store hostnames is now deprecated](https://go.dev/doc/go1.15#commonname):

> The deprecated, legacy behavior of treating the CommonName field on
> X.509 certificates as a host name when no Subject Alternative Names
> are present is now disabled by default. It can be temporarily
> re-enabled by adding the value x509ignoreCN=0 to the GODEBUG
> environment variable.

If you want to find a hostname (or hostname wildcard) within a certification, one should use the `SAN` (Subject Alternative Names) section - where there is a `DNS` section. This is captured in the `DNSNames` field of the [x509.Certificate](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate) struct:

```
log.Printf("DNS names: %+v", cert.DNSNames)

// DNS names: [*.google.com *.appengine.google.com *.bdn.dev *.origin-test.bdn.dev *.cloud.google.com ...
```

---

[Playground Example](https://go.dev/play/p/g7gKzfLw-Gn)

Answer (score 0):

The question is ill-formed, I tink: there's no such thing as "CN" in an X.509 certificate. CN is an abbreviation for "Common Name", which is one form of referring to entities in the X.509 PKI. What you're probably after is the "Subject" field of a certificate—that is, the entity who that certificate was issued for.

If so, you need the `Subject` field of [`x509.Certificate`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate), which is a special compound data type containing `CommonName`, among other things.

See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40048/190156) for a quick overview of what place the CN takes in naming an entity.

The `crypto/x509` is a stock package (that is, provided by the Go's standard library).